# How to make a cell to take full width in LazyVerticalGrid when using GridCells.Adaptive()?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to make a cell to take full width in `LazyVerticalGrid` when using `GridCells.Adaptive()`

When using `GridCells.Fixed()` I can do with the following code but I'm not sure how to do the same with `GridCells.Adaptive()`

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
) {                 
    if (loadMore) {

        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)`

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 80.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
) {

    item(
        span = {
            GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Bottom item")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's ```maxLineSpan```?